# Present Participle

Tags: present-participles

> United Nations peacebuilding activities are aimed at assisting countries emerging from conflict, ***reducing the risk of relapsing into conflict*** and at laying the foundation for sustainable peace and development.

Is the expression in bold present participle which is a complement to ***assisting countries emerging from conflict*** ? or is it an expression that must be considered as continuation of  ***... are aimed at***' as with ***"assisting countries..."*** ? 
I think it must be present participle since ***laying the foundation for sustainable peace and development.*** takes ***at*** in front of it, making itself continuation of ***'...are aimed at'***.

Comment: I think  the activities are aimed at 1)assisting ..., 2)reducing ... and 3)laying. The superfluous *at* before *laying* (or the dropped *at* before *reducing*) is just the sort of carelessness you have to expect of sentences composed of long pompous cliches.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence should be interpreted as below, it is describing 3 distinct things that "peacebuilding activities" that are being "aimed at."  The "at" in the last clause is superfluous and should not be in the sentence.

> United Nations peacebuilding activities are aimed at
>
> - 1. assisting countries emerging from conflict,
> - 2. reducing the risk of relapsing into conflict,
> - 3. and [at] laying the foundation for sustainable peace and development.

*Assisting*, *reducing*, and *laying* are [gerunds](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/gerund/), which is an example of a verb functioning as a noun.